# Why is Rf called Retardation Factor?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, chromatography

I understand that $$R_\mathrm{f} = \frac{\text{distance traveled by center of analyte spot } (b)}{\text{ distance travelled by solvent front } (a)}$$ What I do not understand is why this is called retardation factor; an analyte that travels further in the mobile phase seems to me to be *less* retarded by the stationary phase, while one that doesn't travel as far seems more retarded. If we're using this terminology why doesn't $R_\mathrm{f} = 1- \frac ba$?

Comment: I always learned Rf as being Retention Factor, not Retardation Factor. Your question still stands though...

Comment: They're often used interchangeably in TLC, but IUPAC uses Retardation factor (Rf) for planar chromatography , and Retention factor ( _k_ ) for column chromatography.

Comment: You have the Rf inverted. It should be a/b or distance traveled by the spot divided by distance traveled by the solvent front. Nonetheless, a low value is more retarded or retained, so your question is still a valid one. It seems to be a matter of  definition.

Comment: See also [retention factor $k$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.R05359) and [retardation factor $R_\mathrm F$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.R05353).

Comment: Ah yes,  it is inverted, thanks Dr.J. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest answer is that an analyte is retained by both the mobile and the stationary phase and the retention factor is a measure of the ratio between retention in the mobile phase and in the stationary phase. 
So you could think of it as a higher Rf value indicates a higher retention in the mobile phase.

(Also, in answer to some of the comments, the retardation factor is the inverse of the retention factor)

Comment: That makes sense to me, but I thought that "retention factor" was reserved for discussing column chromatography?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't come across that as a limitation, it may be a convention but I don't think it's a hard rule; I have definitely seen the retardation factor used in reference to TLC, for example, but very rarely.